# Spring XD - Not work with context:annotation-config

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-xd

I define a Spring XD BatchJob that interacting with DB by Spring JPA.
The problems is: Spring XD can Not automatically instantiate a Bean that is configured by JavaConfig and make exception when **Create Definition for Job**

Code for my Bean is:

```
@Service("messageDomainService")
public class MessageDomainService {

    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MessageDomainService(MessageRepository messageRepository) {
        this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
    }

    public void save(Message simpleTweet) {
        messageRepository.save(simpleTweet);
    }
}
```

#

```
public class CustomerTasklet implements Tasklet{

    @Autowired
    private MessageDomainService messageDomainService;

    public CustomerTasklet() {
        super();
    }

    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
            ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        messageDomainService.save(new Message("TEXT"));
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    public MessageDomainService getJdbcCustomerDao() {
        return messageDomainService;
    }

    public void setJdbcCustomerDao(MessageDomainService messageDomainService) {
        this.messageDomainService = messageDomainService;
    }
}
```

And xml at: `src/main/resources/config`

```
   <context:annotation-config/>

    <batch:job id="job">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet ref="customerTasklet" />
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="customerTasklet" class="xxx.CustomerTasklet">
        <property name="messageDomainService" ref="messageDomainService" />
    </bean>
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.xd.moduleoption.postgresql.MessageDomainService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 47 more
}
```

I have also use:

```
@Configuration
@Import(HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories("xxx")
@EntityScan("xxx")
public class BeanConfig {
    @Autowired
    MessageDomainService messageDomainService;  
}
```

And config:
**spring-module.properties:**

```
base_packages=xxx
```

Thanks & Regards,
Loi Le

Comment: What is the name of the package where MessageDomainService is at? Are you sure that package name is covered by base_package ?

Comment: Hello, I have handle package name of MessageDomainService at: @EnableJpaRepositories("xxx")
@EntityScan("xxx")    And config: spring-module.properties:

base_packages=xxx